# Как сделать текст в ячейке таблицы flask-admin короче?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, flask-admin

У меня есть таблица flask-admin и я бы хотел узнать как можно укоротить текст в поле description, чтобы строка так сильно не увеличивалась в размерах[image: скрин таблицы]

Comment: Можете добавить ваш пример кода, которым выформируете таблицу?

Comment: Если вы о вешнем виде, то я просто использую стандартный ModelView

Comment: Получилось проверить, Олег?

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо

Comment: Как сделали? Мой ответ пригодился?

Comment: ```
    def _description_formatter(view, context, model, name):
        return model.description[:20]
```
Никаких правок под свою модель не нужно

Comment: Мой ответ помог вам?

Comment: Да, помог, спасибо

Comment: Хотите подскажу как благодарить за помощь?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyView(ModelView):
     def _description_formatter(..., description, ...):
        return model.description[:20]

    column_formatters = {
        'description': _description_formatter,
    }
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за тупой вопрос, но что нужно указать вместо троеточий?

Comment: Другие колонки вашей модели